# Have some way to put guidelines in JgraphX​​?

Tags: graph, jgraph, mxgraph, jgraphx

I saw that is possible to use guidelines in the javascript version of mxGraph and I would like to know if has some way to do the same in the Java version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, JGraphX does not currently support guidelines. That said, the JavaScript and Java API are, to a greater extent, identical, looking at the JavaScript implementation would give a very good start if you did want to add this to Java.

Note that we (being the collective authors) don't actively add new features to the Java version any longer, it's only bug fixes.

Comment: Thank you. I'll see if it's really necessary to use guidelines and study the javascript API to put this in java.